# Columnas de un ListView

Tags: python, listview

Hola mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de modificar el ancho de las columnas de un listview mediante codigo python

hago una consulta a una tabla en una base de datos pero se ve todo desordenado, quisiera poder ancho fijo a las columnas, y q cada una una se ajuste al contenido

Comment: Hola Marco, deberías dar mas datos y aclarar mas el problema, agregando el código usado de ser posible. ¿De dénde viene ese ListView? ¿es una aplicación web?, ¿una aplicación de escritorio?, ¿que framwork  o bibliotecas usas?, ¿tkinter kivy pyqt, django, etc? Por otro lado  explica que quieres decir con "...ancho fijo.." y con "... cada una se ajuste al contenido ...", porque parece contradictorio. Faltan muchos datos para poder ayudar en algo, `listview` es un concepto difuso y que lo implementa en  gran parte de frameworks para interfaces gŕaficas y sistemas cada uno a su manera. Un saludo.

Comment: buenos dias ok. estoy trabajando con python 3.5,y pyQt4, en un cuadro de dialogo coloco un listview, el cual al cargar los datos de una tabla de una base de datos quedan en 4 columnas pero las columnas (no se cabe decir columnas) me gustaria que tuvieran el mismo ancho para que los datos queden exactamente unos sobre o otros

Comment: Marco un ListView no admite columnas, para ello usa un QTableView o QTreeView . Si quieres simular columnas en un list view podrias crear una vista tu mismo pero es complicarse demasiado por lo general  ( cada fila sea una cadena, concatenando las "columnas" de cada fila, ver cual es la fila mayor y formatear todas las filas para tabularlas conforme a esto por ejemplo). Deberías editar la pregunta mostrando el código usado , la salida que obtienes y la que quedrías obtener.